# mysql timeclock

Tags: mysql

I have a timeclock table with the following elements (`id(pk)`, `action`, `emp_id(fk)`, `time`).

How can I select the latest action if I pass the `emp_id` to the query?

```
id  emp_id  action  current_time
-----------------------------------------------
1   1   clockin     2012-01-29 21:52:38
2   1   clockout    2012-01-29 21:54:24
3   3   clock in    2012-01-30 21:10:51
4   4   clock in    2012-01-30 21:10:51
5   9   clock in    2012-01-30 21:11:05
6   10  clock in    2012-01-30 21:11:05
7   10  go to meal  2012-01-30 21:11:38
8   9   go to meal  2012-01-30 21:11:38
9   9   back        2012-01-30 21:12:53
10  3   back        2012-01-30 21:12:53
11  2   back        2012-01-30 21:12:53
12  1   back        2012-01-30 21:12:53
```

If I write my query like this:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM timeclock WHERE emp_id = 1
```

I get 12 which is right but if i

```
SELECT MAX(ID) , action FROM timeclock WHERE emp_id = 1
```

I get 
`id->12` and `action -> 'clockin'` instead of `'back'` which is definitely not right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `GROUP BY` clause for your `MAX()` aggregate.   The reason you got the correct answer `12` for your first query attempt was merely because that happens to be the greatest ID in the table while also coincidentally belonging to `emp_id = 1`. You would have gotten the same result for any of the `emp_id` values.  A `GROUP BY` clause will sort this out.

Here is an example retrieving the whole row for the associated record:

```
SELECT * FROM timeclock 
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM timeclock WHERE emp_id = 1 GROUP BY emp_id);
```

This can also be done with a `HAVING` clause, not needing the subquery:

```
SELECT action 
FROM timeclock 
WHERE emp_id = 1
GROUP BY emp_id
HAVING id = MAX(id);
```

For reference, [the MySQL aggregate functions reference.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: works fine thanks michael i checked this out at w3schools.com it makes it easy for me to understand