# TimeClock Application: Get time difference between in/out punches

Tags: php, sql, datetime, mysqli

I am creating a time clock application. I have set it up so each user has their own table and it would select that table and all the rows in that table. I want to figure out how to get the difference between the in and next out punch. I am assuming that each in punch will correspond with the next out punch (the next row in the table (when ordering by ID)) I can only think of datediff. I know that is the case, but I have no clue how to implement. I am a very new php developer (Just this past week!) I have no clue how to calculate the difference between each in and out. I have looked at this question: [calculate the difference of the time between In and out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586916/calculate-the-difference-of-the-time-between-in-and-out) but couldn't figure it out there or here: [mysql timeclock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090280/mysql-timeclock). Any help is appreciated.

My exact question is how to get the difference between each in and out punch in a table.

FILE:

```
<head>
    <title>View My Punches</title>
    <body bgcolor="#9966FF">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="http://example.com/time/favicon.ico"/>
</head>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 0);
define('DB_NAME', 'name');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
define('DB_HOST', 'host');


$link = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if ($link->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Could not connect: ' .connect_error());
}
$userid_value = $_POST['userid'];
$table = "tc_".$userid_value;
$checkusersql = "SELECT * FROM tc_users WHERE userid = '$userid_value'";
$usercheck = $link->query($checkusersql);
$punchessql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id";
$result = $link->query($punchessql);
$unixtime = time() + 60*60;
$time_value = date("h:i:s A", $unixtime);
$date_value = date("m/d/Y", $unixtime);
if ($usercheck->num_rows == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, " . $userid_value . " is not a valid user ID. Please try again.";
}else {
    echo "Punch Report for " . $userid_value . "      |       Generated at " . $time_value . " on " . $date_value;
    echo "<p></p>";
    if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
        echo "<p></p>";
        echo "No punches were found for " . $userid_value . ".";
    }else{
        echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr><th>Punch ID</th><th>Time</th><th>Punch Type</th><th>Group</th><th>Department</th><th>Notes</th></tr>";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
        {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['time'] . "</td><td>" . $row['punchtype'] . "</td><td>" . $row['groupname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['dept'] . "</td><td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }

}
$differs = array();
$inout = array();
$current = array('in'=>array(),'out'=>array(),'length'=>'');
foreach ( $row as $each)
{
    if ( $each['punchtype'] == 'in' )
    {
        if ( empty($current['in']) )
        {  $current['in'] = $each;  }
    }
    else if ( $each['punchtype'] == 'out' )
    {
        if ( empty($current['out']) )
        {  $current['out'] = $each;  }
    }

    if (( !empty($current['in']) && !empty($current['out'])))
    {
        $in = new DateTime($current['in']);
        $out = new DateTime($current['out']);
        $current['length'] = $in->diff($out);
        $inout[] = $current; 
        $stamp = $inout['length'];
        $stampformat = $stamp->format('%s');
        $stampint = intval($stampformat);
        $stampintval = $stampint/3600;
        echo $stampintval;
        #array_push($differs, );
  }
}

?>
&nbsp
&nbsp
<form method="GET" action="http://example.com/time/panel.php">
<input type="submit" value="Go Home">
</form>
```

Comment: OK. You're new to `PHP`.  What about `SQL` in general and `MySQL` in particular?

Comment: I am fairly new to them as well. I am getting the hang of select and those type of statements

Comment: What is the exact question here?

Comment: Hi @AdamMiller, some things concern me for sure - "each user has their own table", how does that work when you have hundreds or thousands of employees? It doesn't scale well. I would get a book. Head First SQL was great for me because it runs through database design and SQL usage and is sound information.

Comment: Look into using [TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Comment: I realize that it is not ideal to have each user have their own table, but that is how we had it set up and it would be just to much work to change it. Plus, we are not a business, just a Robotics Club that needs to track time so we never have to worry about that many tables! I do get your point as how hard that would be.

Comment: OK. timediff is the way that I would want to go then. I still have no clue of how to get the in and out pairs.

Comment: What's your table's schema?  Can you post the fields it contains?

Comment: here is my table https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzJ9StkJe55WaG1oaVhqcUJmSGc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be much simpler to do this in PHP instead of in the database.  Let's assume that you've pulled all the records into a variable, $allofit, and that the records are already sorted by your datetime field.  Now you need to pair them up into in-out sets.

```
$inout = array();
$current = array('in'=>array(),'out'=>array(),'length'=>'');
foreach ( $allofit as $each)
{
  if ( $each['punchtype'] == 'in' )
  {  
    if ( empty($current['in']) )
    {  $current['in'] = $each;  }
  }
  else if ( $each['punchtype'] == 'out' )
  {
    if ( empty($current['out']) )
    {  $current['out'] = $each;  }
  }

  if ( !empty($current['in']) && !empty($current['out'])
  {
    $in = new DateTime($current['in']);
    $out = new DateTime($current['out']);
    $current['length'] = $in->diff($out);
    $inout[] = $current;  
  }
}
```

Note that your current schema can have mis-matched in-out sets.  (in @ 1:14, in @ 1:15, out @ 1:40)  This code will silently drop the mismatches; you should probably do what you can to make sure mismatches don't happen in the first place.

Comment: I have the code made so that a user can not do a mismatch punch. They must first have it corrected.

Comment: Super.  Then all you need to do is INSERT the computed time back into your database.

Comment: I was actually planning on putting it into an array so that I could also display the total hours.

Comment: Would you please be so kind as to remind me how to store all of the records into $allofit? Would this be using the fetch_array?

Comment: Yes.  $inout['length'] should contain the difference inside a DateInterval object.  You can get the difference out in whatever format you wish: seconds, minutes with decimals, etc.

Comment: How exactly you get your data into PHP depends on what connection method you use.  I would recommend PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php). You could also use PEAR or even use the mysqli functions directly.  But yes, fetch_array.

Comment: I use mysqli for my connection

Comment: I get this error when I try to run it. Well, actually, I don't get my echo, but then I put it through a php code check and It gave me it. Error: There is 1 array declaration that contain text character variables or values without quotations:
array('in'=>array(),'out'=>array(),'length'=>'');

Comment: I have edited the OP to add the file that I am trying to view it on.

Comment: You shouldn't get that error when you run it.  What are you using as a code check?  Also, on your OP code, you can just print the hours (%h) instead of printing the seconds and converting to hours.